# Spring security no password encoding

Tags: grails, spring-security

Would it be possible to turn off password encoding in Spring Security? If so, how?

Comment: I am not sure about any Configuration settings, but By a small hack in the plugin surely you can,, if you are interested in the hack method, let me know, i will post the required changes, or better a hacked plugin zip :)

Comment: Where's the downvote button for comments ;)  Don't hack the plugin - do it right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a really really bad idea in general, but if you have a use case for it then it is doable. Override the `passwordEncoder` bean in `grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy`:

```
import org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.PlaintextPasswordEncoder

beans = {
   passwordEncoder(PlaintextPasswordEncoder)
}
```

Comment: [There is no excuse for saving passwords in plain text](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/09/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly.html). Normally the use case is, to be able to send password reminders by email. But it's easy to instead implement the similar feature that sends an email enabling to reset the password. If the customer of a civil engineer, asks to build something without the required fire exists, the civil engineer will say it's not possible, and ultimately walk away if it's a demand. As software developers, we would say, yes, alright, I can do that!

Comment: @stivlo - while I generally agree with this, there *is* a reasonable application for plaintext password encoding, which is for use in a development/testing environment in order to be able to verify that passwords are being correctly stored in the database with a simple test.  This should ideally be coupled with an after-deployment live system test that checks that passwords *aren't* being stored in plain, but it can be a useful part of an automated testing system.