# Spring security , password with non-English characters like "š, č, ć, ž, đ" login failed

Tags: grails, spring-security, special-characters

I have Grails app with spring-security-core plugin. In my conf/spring/resources.groovy file I defined

```
import org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.PlaintextPasswordEncoder
beans = {
    passwordEncoder(PlaintextPasswordEncoder)
}
```

so I can save plain text passwords in MySql DB like it was explained here [Spring security no password encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465016/spring-security-no-password-encoding)

in views/login/auth.gsp I also added in `<head>` block

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

and in Datasource.groovy

```
url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/blabla?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8"
```

I created User with username = ččč and password = ččč succesfully , but when I try to login with this user I get login error "Sorry, we were not able to find a user with that username and password." I checked database and user exists with those field values.

I tried to login with some other user that has username = admin , password = admin , and it works fine.
So I guess that it has something to do with j_username and j_password not accepting non-English characters ... How to enable login form fields to accept utf-8 character set?

I have:

Grails 1.3.7

Spring-Security-Core 1.2.6

STS 2.8.1

mysql-connector-java-5.1.18

Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

First advice: don't use plaintext passwords. Second advice: check what SQL queries are sent to database. You need this in your Config.groovy to see Hibernate statements and its parameter values:

```
log4j = { 
        debug 'org.hibernate.SQL' 
        trace 'org.hibernate.type' 
}
```

Comment: I know I should't use plaintext password but this is some simple project and plaintext is really what I needed ... anyway after implementing this in Config.groovy I see in console

DEBUG dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider  - User 'Ä?Ä?Ä?' not found

...and for login username I typed ččč , not Ä?Ä?Ä? ... so I guess the question is still why the field is not accepting utf-8 character set? And how do I make it do so :(